# How to get value from 2 different row of table in 1 row to save in temp table in mssql

Tags: sql-server, rows

I have a `aff_attributes` table which has data

```
att_id  aff_id   att_name   att_value
978    12        address1   123 agajanian drive
979    12        zip        97654
980    12        city       canyon country
```

so I want to store it in temp table, with 1 row

```
affid     address1               zip   city
12        123 agajanian drive    97654   canyon country
```

Comment: At least consider formatting your post. BTW, you are looking for `PIVOTING`. Search in Google and lots of sample can be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `PIVOT`  something like.....

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT aff_id
            ,att_name
            ,att_value
      FROM aff_attributes
   ) t
 PIVOT (MAX(att_value)
        FOR att_name
        IN (address1, zip, City))p
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much...appreciate the help